# How to cancel NSURLRequest from within UIWebView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I was looking at this posting where the op says he is canceling requests in web view:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:

[How to do authentication in UIWebView properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999776/how-to-do-authentication-in-uiwebview-properly)

How is that possible? I don't see any API on NSURLRequest to cancel it. I know its possible to cancel an NSURLConnection, if the op meant to say NSURLConnection in the posting instead of NSURLRequest, then how do you obtain the underlying NSURLConnection from within a UIWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSURLRequest` isn't itself a process to be canceled, so there's no API for it. When a UIWebView sends its delegate a `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` message, it's asking whether it should start the process of fetching data from / posting data to a URL -- the `NSURLRequest` parameter is an object which simply describes that proposed action, not the object which performs it. (If UIWebView is using an underlying NSURLConnection, it hasn't created it yet; that's what it's asking to do.) "Canceling the request" is simply a matter of returning `NO` from that method.

Comment: @Mr. Peckington: True, writing is on the [wall](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)