# WKWebView and authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, ios8, wkwebview

I'm trying to get authentication to work with my WKWebView with no success. I've tried the the usual methods i.e setting the credentials in the shared storage ([How to do authentication in UIWebView properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999776/how-to-do-authentication-in-uiwebview-properly)), using a NSURLConnection to catch the authentication challenge ([How to display the Authentication Challenge in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview)).

Anyone got any suggestions?

The authentication works in Safari so is should work. Apple could of course use something hidden...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solved it in beta 3 using the function didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge in WKNavigationDelegate. I've tried it and it works perfectly

Comment: Don't know. I have no experience with SharePoint

Comment: Hello Taj rajan,  does it work for Sharepoint,  have you figured it out?