# Swift - UIWebView baseURL resulting in blank screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I need to show a web browser in my app. I can't use SFSafariViewController as I need to be able to authenticate with NTLM, so I'm currently using Alamofire to download the `data` and then displaying it in a UIWebView.

I have got the UIWebView to display the HTML via `.loadHTMLString()`, however the images, CSS and Javascript files are not loading. I tried setting the `baseURL` to the website root, however, when I do this nothing at all loads in the `UIWebView`, leaving it blank with no content or errors in the console.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://dev-moss.stpaulscatholiccollege.co.uk/sites/Students/default.aspx").authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
    .response { request, response, data, error in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            // check for errors or bad responsecode
            if (error == nil) && (response?.statusCode == 200) {
                // load the website
                let gatewayString = "\(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))"

                self.gatewayWebView.loadHTMLString(String(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!), baseURL: nil)
                print(gatewayString)

            }
            else {
                print("There was an error loading the website.")
            }

        })

}
```

Even when setting the `baseURL` to `NSURL(string: "https://dev-moss.stpaulscatholiccollege.co.uk/")` or `NSURL(string: "https://dev-moss.stpaulscatholiccollege.co.uk")` the `print` of `gatewayString` still spits out the website to the console however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because the base URL isn't `https://dev-moss.stpaulscatholiccollege.co.uk/`, it's `https://dev-moss.stpaulscatholiccollege.co.uk/sites/Students/default.aspx`. Try that and it should work.

**Edit:**

It looks like it's not working because `https://dev-moss.stpaulscatholiccollege.co.uk/sites/Students/default.aspx` uses HTTP Basic Authentication, which you have not provided credentials for (the UIWebView makes a separate requests for resources from your one made via Alamofire, which doesn't include your credentials.) See [How to do authentication in UIWebView properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999776/how-to-do-authentication-in-uiwebview-properly)

Comment: Unfortunately still not working with that base URL; shows white screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Matt, didn't think of that. Looks like it's going to become a bit more complex - if only SFSafariViewController had an authentication prompt delegate.

Comment: @James There's also `WKWebView`, which does have one.